# Processmaker getField javascript error

Tags: php, javascript

I have a problem when creating a process maker dynaform in which in task 1, a form uploads a document, in form 2 i want a link to that document to be able to download it (this is for testing purposes for the company I work for).

My problem is that following the documentation on the process maker website [Links to input Documents in Dnyaforms](http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/Input_Documents#Links_to_Input_Documents_in_DynaForms) it doesn't work.

Enabling debug mode on the trigger, the URL is coming out fine, all ID's being referenced are fine, the only problem I can find is the getField function is returning null, where it should be returning an object where I can call its .value property.

Has anyone had this issue before? or am I just doing something stupid?

Trigger code:

```
$caseId = @@APPLICATION;
$query = "SELECT C.CON_ID, C.CON_VALUE FROM APP_DOCUMENT AD, CONTENT C
   WHERE AD.APP_UID='$caseId' AND AD.APP_DOC_TYPE='INPUT' AND AD.APP_DOC_STATUS='ACTIVE'
   AND AD.APP_DOC_UID=C.CON_ID AND C.CON_CATEGORY='APP_DOC_FILENAME' AND C.CON_VALUE<>''";
$result = executeQuery($query);
if (is_array($result) and count($result) > 0) {
   $caseDocId = $result[1]['CON_ID'];
   @@inputFileURL = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/sys' . @@SYS_SYS . '/' . 
      @@SYS_LANG . '/' . @@SYS_SKIN . '/cases/cases_ShowDocument?a=' . $caseDocId;
   @@inputFilename = $result[1]['CON_VALUE'];
}
```

Javascript code:

```
window.onload = function() 
  { 
    getField("lnkTimesheet").href = getField("inputFileURL").value; 
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I had read the documentation correctly on [the process maker wiki](http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/Input_Documents#Links_to_Input_Documents_in_DynaForms).

The answer was to create a hidden field with the same name as the php variable, thus it can load the variable into the hidden field and the javascript would get the value from the hidden field and put it into the href of the link.

The php variable can only be loaded into input elements as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've just added an example on our ProcessMaker Documentation which involves the creation of a dynaform with the possibility to insert a direct link to open/download an Input Document in a Dynaform, it includes an example, you can check the example [here](http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/2.0/Input_Documents#Links_to_multiple_Input_Document_files_in_DynaForms)

Regards.

Liliana

[processmaker](/questions/tagged/processmaker)